# How to initialize a variable which is a pointer to array of pointers to structure?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I need to call a function from a third party source. The function expects a parameter of the following type:

```
StructureName *(*parameterName)[]
```

In an example it is defined as array of pointers:

```
StructureName * MagneticModels[1]
```

It is passed to the function with "&" operator. Unfortunately in Visual Studio 2013 it fails to compile:

> `Error C2664: (...) cannot convert argument (...) from 'StructureName *(*)[1]' to 'StructureName *(*)[]'`

So to get it to compile I added a new variable and passed it to the function:

```
StructureName *(*variableName)[];
```

Now it compiles without error but then I get a runtime error that the "variableName" is used without being initialized.

I tried many ways to initialize that but I am not a C++ developer so it was real ordeal and after a day I did not get nowhere. Therefore, I would appreciate any help or suggestion.

Comment: Can you provide any actual code snippet, instead of hints?

Comment: Which language are you using? (C and C++ have different rules about incomplete array types in some cases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C the following code is legal (where `T` is your structure name or whatever):

```
void foo( T *(*ptr)[] )
{ }

int main()
{
    T *arr[1];
    foo( &arr );
}
```

However that function prototype is illegal in C++ (let alone the call).

If you are trying to write C code then make sure you are invoking the C compiler, not the C++ compiler.

If you are trying to write C++ but call this function (whose header must be written in C and presumably the function was implemented in C also), then you will need to write a stub function which has a legal prototype in C++.

For example:

```
// stub.h
void foo2( T **ptr );    // preferably use "extern C" guards around this
```

and

```
// stub.c
#include "foo.h"           // the troublesome function 

void foo2( T **ptr )
{
    foo( (T *(*)[]) ptr );
}
```

This stub will be invoked by passing the address of the first element, rather than the address of the entire array:

```
T * MagneticModels[1];
foo2( MagneticModels );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought that C is always compatible with C++. Good to learn something new. And now it works :)

Answer (score 1):

If the function requires a `StructureName *(*parameterName)[]` parameter, then the only way to pass a pointer to a `StructureName * MagneticModels[1]` array to such function is to use a `&` operator with an explicit cast

```
foo((StructureName *(*)[]) &MagneticModels);
```

(It can be made more readable by using a `typedef` to the array type).

Another loophole is based on the fact that an array can be *declared* with unknown size and then *defined* with a specific size. As long as only the "unknown size" declaration is known to the compiler at the point of the call, it will allow you to pass it without a cast

```
extern StructureName * MagneticModels[]; // declaration

void foo(StructureName * MagneticModels[]);

int main()
{
  foo(&MagneticModels);
}

StructureName * MagneticModels[1] = { ... }; // definition
```

The applicability of this loophole is, of course, very limited.